# how to initialize pointer with array using constructor C++

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, struct, constructor

creat a pointer in struct creat array initialize -1, 10 times using for loop and print -1, 10 times using method in struct.

```
struct hasha {
    int* arr;
    int l;
    hasha(int no) {
        arr[no];
        l = no;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            arr[i] = -1;
        }
    }
    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
        }
    }
};
int main() {
    hasha a(10);
    a.print();
}
```

Comment: whoever gave you this taks should also have provided you the required basics, see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Use `std::vector`, else you have to do allocation/deallocation manually.

Comment: `std::vector<int> a(10, -1); for (auto e : a) {std::cout << e << " ";}`.

Comment: What does "creat" mean?

Comment: `arr[no]` does not create an array. Review the things you’ve learned recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is for learning purposes, otherwise you should be using a `std::vector<int>` for this.

```
struct hasha {
    int* arr;
    size_t l;                // size_t is an unsigned int type better suited for sizes

    hasha(size_t no) :       // use the member initializer list (starting with ":")
        arr(new int[no]),    // create the array
        l(no)
    {
        // initialize the array with -1, "l" times using a for loop
        for (size_t i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            arr[i] = -1;
        }
    }

    // You need to delete the implicitly declared copy ctor and copy assignment operator
    // to forbid copying hasha objects to not free the `int*` multiple times later.
    hasha(const hasha&) = delete;
    hasha& operator=(const hasha&) = delete;

    // You need a destructor to free the memory you allocated:
    ~hasha() {
        delete[] arr;
    }

    void print() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: *"unsigned int type better suited for sizes"*. While I agree, it is opened for debates ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 :-) True. It's also a bit tricky to use it consistently.

Answer (score -1):

The following constructor initialises the pointer with an array:
`hasha ::hasha (int a[]) : arr (a) {}`

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this. It doesn't initialize an array, it sets the pointer to an external array. It is incompatible with the question's goals.

Comment: This is exactly what the author asked for.

Comment: This does not create an array of 10 values at -1, and is not compatible with the shown `main` function. You misunderstood the question.

Comment: The only part I can understand from the question is the summary, so I replied to what I was able to understand.

Comment: In the future, you can ask for clarification in the question's comments section.